# ImportError (unknown location) despite class clearly being present in the module

Tags: python, python-import, importerror

I am trying to import the class Stockfish from the stockfish python package ([github](https://github.com/zhelyabuzhsky/stockfish/tree/master/stockfish)) using:

```
from stockfish import Stockfish
```

which [the description of the same project](https://pypi.org/project/stockfish/) says we should do.

The python package on github has a file `__init__.py` that imports Stockfish, so it really should work, and yet I am getting the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "XXXXX", line 1, in <module>
    from stockfish import Stockfish
ImportError: cannot import name 'Stockfish' from 'stockfish' (unknown location)
```

What could be going on here? A google search tells me that this error should only happen if Stockfish is not actually in the stockfish package, but it seems to clearly be in there.

Comment: open python shell and try to import it from there. could be that you're using different python interpreter from which you've installed package into

Comment: After some experimentation, I figured out that `unknown location` is trying to display the location of the module, but failed. If you actually have an `__init__.py` file in the `stockfish` directory, it will show the path to that file. So I suspect that you have added the root of the `stockfish` repo to your Python path, instead of the `stockfish` directory _inside_ that repo, which contains the necessary `__init__.py` file that makes it into a Python package. If you use `pip` or similar to install the package from PyPI, this sort of mistake should not happen.

Comment: @AlexBender, yes you seem to be right, when I command 'python' in my terminal and then do it there, it just works. How do I know which interpreter I should use in vscode so that it's the same as where I installed `stockfish`? I must say though, I'm a little confused because if I just write `import stockfish` instead of `from stockfish import Stockfish` then that *doesn't* give an error even in vscode (but then I get an error if I write `stockfish.Stockfish`).

Comment: @user56834 command "which python" shows you which interpreter is currently is use. Also  take a look at "which pip". At the down right corner of VSCode you can select interpreter. Also, you can use pip as "python -m pip ..."